# Sending Stata output to a logfile under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, stata

I write the Stata do-file and run it with a script code under the Ubuntu system.

The .sh file with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
stata -b do mydofile.do
```

It will generate a log file with the name of mydofile.log after running the .sh code.
My question is how to specify the path and name of this log file?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect `stdrr` and `stdout` (or both) of `stata` program to file doing like so.

```
#!/bin/bash

stata -b do mydofile.do &>>/path/to/mydofile.log
```

Here is more [context](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

- `1>filename` -  Redirect stdout to filename.
- `1>>filename` - Redirect and append stdout to filename.
- `2>filename` - Redirect stderr to filename.
- `2>>filename` - Redirect and append stderr to filename.
- `&>filename` - Redirect both stdout and stderr to filename.
- `&>>filename` - Redirect both stdout and stderr and append to filename.

Comment: Does this still work with #delimit; and /* */ comments?

Comment: I don't know that.

Comment: See [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/unix/batch-mode/).